# How to serialise classes for UDP discover and TCP connection using boost::asio

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I trying to learn how to use boost::asio.  C++ and ASYNC is very different to my normal programming practices.

I am trying to write a program that discovers a device using UDP and then establishes a TCP connection to it.  Once the TCP connection is established the program stops UDP searching stops.  Should the TCP connection disconnect or timeout the UDP search starts again.

I have watch many videos today including https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FQwAjELMek.  I have loosely based my code on the shared pointer idiom discussed as that seems to be the closest I have gotten to a solution.

I have developed two classes.

- udpFindQSYNC that I can use to search for the device using UDP/
- tcpQSYNC that I can use to establish a connection to the device using TCP.

To test my program - I start it, then I fake a UDP response using  netcat and then let the TCP connection timeout by using a non existent IP address to try get the program to loop back into the search.

echo "hello" | nc -lu 0.0.0.0 9720

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

class tcpQSYNC : public std::enable_shared_from_this<tcpQSYNC> {

public:
    tcpQSYNC(boost::asio::io_context &ioc, std::string hostname, unsigned int tcpPort) :
            m_socket(ioc, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 0)),
            m_timer(ioc)
    {
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(ioc);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(hostname, std::to_string(tcpPort));
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
        m_remoteEndpoint = *endpoint_iterator;
    }

    ~tcpQSYNC() {
        std::cout << "tcpQSYNC destructor" << std::endl;
    }

    void run () {
        startConnection ();
        std::cout << "TCP Connection Started" << std::endl;
    }

    void startConnection() {
        m_socket.async_connect(m_remoteEndpoint,
                               [self = shared_from_this()](boost::system::error_code errorCode) {
                                   self->onConnectHandler(errorCode);
                               });
    }

    void onConnectHandler(const boost::system::error_code& error) {return;}
private:
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket m_socket;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint m_remoteEndpoint;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer m_timer;
};

class udpFindQSYNC : public std::enable_shared_from_this<udpFindQSYNC> {
public:
    udpFindQSYNC(boost::asio::io_context &ioc, unsigned int udpPort) :
            m_socket(ioc, boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4(), 0)),
            m_localEndpoint(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::broadcast(), udpPort),
            m_timer(ioc) {

        m_socket.set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
        m_socket.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::broadcast(true));
    }

    ~udpFindQSYNC() {
        std::cout << "udpFindQSYNC() destructor" << std::endl;
    }

    void run() {
        sendUDPBroadcast();
    }

    void sendUDPBroadcast() {
        std::array<uint8_t, 2> data = {{0, 0}};

        m_socket.async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(data, 2), m_localEndpoint,
                               [self = shared_from_this()](boost::system::error_code errorCode, std::size_t bytes) {
                                   self->onBroadcastComplete(errorCode, bytes);
                               });
    }

    void onBroadcastComplete(const boost::system::error_code &errorCode, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
        if (errorCode == boost::system::errc::success) {
            std::cout << "UDP Broadcast "<< bytes_transferred << " byte"<< ((bytes_transferred==1) ? "" : "s") << std::endl;
            queueRead();
            createTimer();
        } else {
            std::cout << __func__ << " (" << errorCode.message() << ")" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void createTimer() {
        // 10 second retry timer
        m_timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(10000));
        m_timer.async_wait(
                [self = shared_from_this()] (boost::system::error_code errorCode)
                {
                    self->onTimerExpiry(errorCode);
                });
    }

    void queueRead() {
        m_socket.async_receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(m_buffer), m_remoteEndpoint,
                                    [self = shared_from_this()](boost::system::error_code errorCode, std::size_t bytes) {
                                        self->onReceiveData(errorCode, bytes);
                                    });
    }

    void onTimerExpiry(const boost::system::error_code &errorCode) {
        if (errorCode == boost::system::errc::success) {
            std::cout << "UDP Timer Expired" << std::endl;
            // Timer has expired.   Cancel outstanding read operation and start again
            m_socket.cancel();
            sendUDPBroadcast();
        } else if (errorCode == boost::system::errc::operation_canceled){
            std::cout << "Timer Operation Cancelled " << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void onReceiveData(const boost::system::error_code &errorCode, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
        // Read has completed. Cancel the timer.
        m_timer.cancel();
        if (errorCode == boost::system::errc::success) {
            std::cout << "UDP Received Data " << bytes_transferred << " byte" <<((bytes_transferred==1) ? " " : "s ") << getIPAddress() << std::endl;
        } else if (errorCode == boost::system::errc::operation_canceled) {
            std::cout << "UDP Read Operation Cancelled " << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::string getIPAddress() {
        std::cout << "Called getIPAddress() " << m_remoteEndpoint.address().to_string() << std::endl;
        return m_remoteEndpoint.address().to_string();
    }
private:
    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket m_socket;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint m_localEndpoint;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint m_remoteEndpoint;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer m_timer;

    std::array<uint8_t, 32> m_buffer = {0};
};

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context ioc;
    boost::asio::io_context::strand strand(ioc);

    int loop =0;
    while (loop < 2) {
        auto udp = std::make_shared<udpFindQSYNC>(ioc, 9720);
        udp->run();
        std::string remote = udp->getIPAddress();  // Should return 192.168.0.140 in my case.
        std::cout << "Main " << remote << std::endl;

        // I want to get the address returned from the udpFindQSYNC.
        // I have hard code to no existant IP to cause timeout

        std::string nonextisthostname("192.168.0.143");
        std::make_shared<tcpQSYNC>(ioc, nonextisthostname, 9760)->run();

        loop++;
        // Run the I/O service on the main thread
        ioc.run();
```

Things I cannot get my head around

1. How I return the IP address from the udpFindQSYNC class for the tcpQSYNC class to connect too.  As the udpFindQSYNC destructor has been called.
2. How I use the io_context to run two separate classes sequentially in essentially an infinite loop.

I looked a strands, but cannot figure out how to use in my context.  I always see the TCP connection run concurrently to the UDP

The log producted my program is:

```
UDP Broadcast 2 bytes
tcpQSYNC destructor
UDP Timer Expired
UDP Read Operation Cancelled 
UDP Broadcast 2 bytes
UDP Received Data 6 bytes Called getIPAddress() 192.168.0.140
192.168.0.140
Timer Operation Cancelled 
udpFindQSYNC() destructor      <- My class is detroyed
Called getIPAddress() 0.0.0.0   
Main 0.0.0.0                   <- Thus my result is wrong   
TCP Connection Started
tcpQSYNC destructor
udpFindQSYNC() destructor
```

Would someone be able to point me towards the best way to address the two problems I cannot figure out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `getIPAddress` can be called afer `onReceiveData` handler was called or within this method.

Your problem is that `getIPAddress` is called too early,  `m_remoteEndpoint` is not filled yet, because `udp->run()` returns immediately and handler - `onReceiveData` was not called.

Possible solutions to your problem:

1) add some blocking mechanism in `getIPAddress` which blocks until `onReceiveData` was called, then `getIPAddress` can end and return `m_remoteEndpoint` address

2) you are calling `getIPAddress` from `onReceiveData`

First way can be achived for example by using `condition_variable` and `isAddress` flag. Inside `getIPAddress` you are calling `wait` on condition variable with predicate which checks if `isAddress` is set to true. In handler `onReceiveData` you set `isAddress` to true, and notify condition variable. The weakness of this approach is that in `main` you need to start additional thread (in background) in which `ioc.run()` works - to handle handlers. Without this `main` thread will be blocked on `getIPAddress` method.

In second way the main loop can be reduced to:

```
int loop =0;
while (loop < 2) 
{
    auto udp = std::make_shared<udpFindQSYNC>(ioc, 9720);
    udp->run();

    loop++;
    // Run the I/O service on the main thread
    ioc.run();
}
```

and I think this is what you want. You start first async operation in `udp->run` and the rest work is performed in handlers.

When `tcpQSYNC` is created? In `onReceiveData` because then you know the address of the other side which you want to connect to.

```
void onReceiveData(const boost::system::error_code &errorCode, std::size_t bytes_transferred) 
{
    m_timer.cancel();
    if (errorCode == boost::system::errc::success) {
        std::cout << "UDP Received Data " << bytes_transferred << " byte" <<((bytes_transferred==1) ? " " : "s ") << getIPAddress() << std::endl;
     // m_remoteEndpoint is filled here
    std::make_shared<tcpQSYNC>(ioc, m_remoteEndpoint.address().to_string(), 9760)->run();

    } else if (errorCode == boost::system::errc::operation_canceled) {
        std::cout << "UDP Read Operation Cancelled " << std::endl;
    }
}
```

---

This

```
std::array<uint8_t, 2> data = {{0, 0}};

m_socket.async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(data, 2), m_localEndpoint,
          [self = shared_from_this()](boost::system::error_code errorCode, std::size_t bytes) {
                self->onBroadcastComplete(errorCode, bytes);
          });
```

is undefined behaviour. `data` is local. `async_send_to` returns immediately. `boost::asio::buffer` doesn't make a copy of passed buffer.

You can store `data` as data member of your class to ensure that buffer lives for the whole time while `async_send_to` is being performed. Or put it into `shared_ptr` and pass smart pointer to lambda by value - lifetime of data will be prolonged.

---

In `tcpQSYNC`, why are you passing endpoint to `m_socket`?

```
m_socket(ioc, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 0))
```

this constructor will bind socket to the given endpoint. What for? You are a client, not server.
You should pass only protocol:

```
m_socket(ioc,boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4()),
```