# Learning boost::asio - by implementing UDP device discovery with TCP connection

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, asio

I am trying to learn how to use boost::asio.

I am trying to write a program that searches for a device using UDP and then establishes a TCP connection to that device and then exchanges messages.  If the TCP connection drops, I want to resume the UDP search and reestablish a new TCP connection.  Basically in an infinite loop.

My code is based on that provided in [How to serialise classes for UDP discover and TCP connection using boost::asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57231816/how-to-serialise-classes-for-udp-discover-and-tcp-connection-using-boostasio) with the suggestions list there implemented.

The issue that I have is the TCP Client never connects to the device to read the data.

I've created a minimum example of the problem.  See instructions to simulate.  To test the code - after compiling using `g++ -o test test.cpp -lpthread` you need three terminals - I used debian 11 linux

Test 1 - Fails to connect and read the data

Terminal 1 - `echo -e '\x00' | nc -l 0.0.0.0 9001`
Terminal 2 - `echo "X" | nc -lu 0.0.0.0 9000`

Terminal 3 - `./test`

```
UDP Client Found 192.168.0.10
TCP Client connecting to 192.168.0.10
TCPClient completed in udpFindClient->onReceiveData()
TCP Client destructor
UDP Timer Expired
UDP Read Operation Cancelled
```

Test 2 - Connects and reads the data - but doesn't make sense.

Interesting - which does not make sense if I un-comment - line 23 `ioc_.run()`.  It appears to work.   But why do I need another ioc.run()?  I am confused.

Terminal 1 - `echo -e '\x00' | nc -l 0.0.0.0 9001`
Terminal 2 - `echo "X" | nc -lu 0.0.0.0 9000`

Terminal 3 - `./test`

```
UDP Client Found 192.168.0.10
TCP Client connecting to 192.168.0.10
TCP Client Connected to
TCP Client read message
TCP Client read message
```

As far as I can see the code should run in the io.run() in main.  The chaining of the ASYNC functions should keep the application running.

What is wrong with my code that causes the test 1 to fail?  What next steps could I take to work out what is wrong?

Thanks
Densha

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::asio::ip::udp;

class tcpClient  {
public: tcpClient(boost::asio::io_context & ioc, std::string hostname, unsigned int tcpPort):
    ioc_(ioc),
    socket_(ioc)
    {
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(
            boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(hostname),tcpPort);
        cout << "TCP Client connecting to "<< endpoint.address().to_string() << endl;
        socket_.async_connect(endpoint,
                            boost::bind( & tcpClient::onConnect, this,
                                        boost::asio::placeholders::error));
//COMMENTED OUT       ioc_.run();
    }

    ~tcpClient() {
        cout << "TCP Client destructor" << endl;
    }

private:
    void close() {
    socket_.close();
    }

void onConnect(const boost::system::error_code & error) {
    if (!error) {
    cout << "TCP Client Connected" << endl;
    requestInformation();
    readResponse();
    }
}

// Request Information
void requestInformation() {
    boost::asio::write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(requestInfo,1));
}

void readResponse() {
    boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
    boost::asio::buffer(message, 1),
    boost::bind( & tcpClient::onreadResponse, this,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

void onreadResponse(const boost::system::error_code & error, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
    if (!error) {
    cout << "TCP Client read message" << endl;
    readResponse();
    } else {
    cout << "readVariableLengthData failed " << error << endl;
    }
}

private:
    boost::asio::io_context & ioc_;
    tcp::socket socket_;
    std::array < unsigned char, 255 > message;
    std::array < uint8_t, 2 > requestInfo = {{ 0x0, 0x0 }};

};

class udpFindClient {
public:
    udpFindClient(boost::asio::io_context & ioc, unsigned int udpPort): localEndpoint_(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::broadcast(), udpPort),
    socket_(ioc, boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4(), 0)),
    timer_(ioc),
    ioc_(ioc)
    {
        socket_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
        socket_.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::broadcast(true));
    }

    ~udpFindClient() {
    }

    void run() {
        sendUDPBroadcast();
    }

    void sendUDPBroadcast() {
        socket_.async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(data, 2), localEndpoint_,
                            boost::bind(& udpFindClient::onBroadcastComplete, this,
                                        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }

    void onBroadcastComplete(const boost::system::error_code & errorCode, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
        if (errorCode == boost::system::errc::success) {
            queueRead();
            createTimer();
        }
    }

    void createTimer() {
        // 10 second retry timer
        timer_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(10000));
        timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(& udpFindClient::onTimerExpiry, this,
                                    boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void onTimerExpiry(const boost::system::error_code & errorCode) {
        if (errorCode == boost::system::errc::success) {
            std::cout << "UDP Timer Expired" << std::endl;
            // Timer has expired.   Cancel outstanding read operation and start again
            socket_.cancel();
            sendUDPBroadcast();
        }
    }

    void queueRead() {
        socket_.async_receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(m_buffer), remoteEndpoint_,
                                    boost::bind(& udpFindClient::onReceiveData, this,
                                                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }

    void onReceiveData(const boost::system::error_code & errorCode, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
        // Read has completed. Cancel the timer.
        timer_.cancel();
        if (errorCode == boost::system::errc::success) {
            std::cout << "UDP Client Found " <<  remoteEndpoint_.address().to_string() << std::endl;
            tcpClient t (ioc_, remoteEndpoint_.address().to_string(), 9001);
            std::cout << "TCPClient completed in udpFindClient->onReceiveData()" << std::endl;
            sendUDPBroadcast();
        } else if (errorCode == boost::system::errc::operation_canceled) {
            std::cout << "UDP Read Operation Cancelled " << std::endl;
        }
    }

private: boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket_;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint localEndpoint_;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint remoteEndpoint_;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer_;
    boost::asio::io_context & ioc_;

    std::array < uint8_t, 2 > data = {{ 0, 0 }};
    std::array < uint8_t, 32 > m_buffer = { 0 };
};

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context ioc;
    unsigned int udpPort = 9000;
    udpFindClient udp (ioc, udpPort);
    udp.run();
    ioc.run();
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce Test1. Are you sure that you tried with exactly the code and commands you posted?

Comment: You should have a look at the livetime of the `t` variable in the `onReceiveData` function. When it goes out of scope (at the end of the `if` block), the tcp client is destroyed. You should store it somewhere in a non-local variable or use something like `std::enable_shared_from_this` to keep the tcp client alive after the udp client started it.

Comment: Yes exact same code. Thankyou, yes you are correct about lifetime of ```t```.   That makes sense.  In review the logic of the code requires the tcpClient to remain in existence - almost block until it exits - because once it exits it starts the UDP search again.   This part of the program needs to be redesigned.   The logic for the creation and destruction of the tcpClient needs rethinking.  Do you have any suggestions about the best approach to handle this in udpClient->onReceiveData().